# Defining function through a formula

Tags: function-construction, group-theory, random-process, circles

I would like to define a cocycle on a group that maps into the unit circle. That is, I want to be able to define a function $f:G\times G\to\mathbb{T}$ such that $f(e_G,a)=f(a,e_G)=1$ for all $a\in G$ and $f(g,h)f(gh,k)=f(h,k)f(g,hk)$. In my case, $G=SymmetricGroup[4]$, and I would like Mathematica to randomly define $f$ with the previous mentioned properties. I am fairly new with this language, and I am not even sure if this is possible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "randomly define $f$ with the previous mentioned properties" is more of a *mathematics* problem at first, because you need to figure out what that actually means ("random": what distribution are you pulling from? - "define": how are you doing the sampling? - etc.). Once you've got that in hand, a Mathematica implementation will be straight-forward, but those details need to be sorted first.

Comment: One way might be to first generate a list of *all* possible functions (I feel like there are only a finite number of them, or at least a finite number of collections of such functions that can be separately parameterized, but my intuition might be wrong there).  Then, one can decide on what "random" means (e.g., a uniform distribution, normal, etc.), and from there simulate the random choice.